# JfreeChart - XYPlot, selecting tasks?

Tags: task, jfreechart

Is there a way to select one of several tasks contained in a XYPlot ?
I mean, imagine you have several tasks in a XYPlot, I would like to select several tasks in one go in order later to delete them. The fact that mouse draging enables zoom in and zoom out, I do not find another solution.

Any suggestion to select these tasks ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative, consider adding a [`JTable`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html), which supports a number of selection models and a more familiar interface. `CrosshairDemo1` and `CrosshairDemo1` are examples found in the [demo](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/samples.html).